# SQL Server select with aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table that looks like this(this is just some of the records and their are also more columns too but these are the ones I care about):

```
nbr    amt     date     
1      10      10/30/2012
1      15      1/30/2012
1      50      11/30/2012
2      10      4/30/2012
2      1000    5/30/2012
2      45      1/15/2012
4      90      12/30/2012
4      89      8/30/2012
3      100     7/30/2012
```

I'm trying to select the nbr,amt, and date that corresponds to the max(amt) for each nbr using SQL Server 2012.

I have query like this so far which groups it by nbr and selects the max(amt) but it won't let me select date because its not in an aggregate function but if I put it in an aggregate function it selects max(date) which doesn't corrsepond to the actual date that goes with the amt:

```
,topamt as (
select 
                 nbr
    ,amt
    ,date
,amtrank = row_number() over (partition by ah.member_nbr order by ah.tran_amt desc)

from HISTORY ah 
      amt>=10
and id=6061
and date between '11-01-2012' and '12-31-2012'
```

so if I change the query to this where am I defining it to grab the max(amt) the results aren't showing the max atleast.

Comment: If you have the same max amt that occurred on two different days, would you want the first time you hit that amount or the most recent time that hit that amount?

Comment: doesn't matter whichever is easier to implement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a ranking function:

```
with TopAmt as
(
  select *
  , amtRank = row_number() over (partition by nbr order by amt desc)
)
select nbr
  , amt
  , date
from TopAmt
where amtRank = 1
```

Comment: +1, this will always retrieve one record. If there is more than one record with the same max `amt` per `nbr`, then op can use `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue but the table I'm looking at has more than 3 columns, those are just the ones i care about. I get the error:nbr was specified multiple times for topamt

Comment: @Lamak makes a good point; you can include date in the over clause if you're worried about a tie breaker, e.g. (partition by nbr order by amt desc, date) will return the first occurrence of the max amt.

Comment: yes I've row_number() over(partition... before and yes it retrives one record but it's not select the max.

Comment: please take a look at question/query above I edited for what I think u suggested

Comment: @ERead No, that is not what Ian suggested since I don't see the most important part of the solution in your code, the `WHERE amtRank = 1` part

Comment: Sory yes I have that part too.